# Lower bound for Probability of Maximum of Normal Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X_{i}$ are iid $N(0,1)$ distributed. I have to show that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$ P\Big(max_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i \geq c \sqrt{ log(n)} \Big) \geq 0.5 $$

But I don't even know where I should start. If someone could nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: For a  start $P(max_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i \geq c \sqrt{ log(n)} ) =1-P(X_1 < c\sqrt {\log n})^{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y = \max_{1\le i \le n} X_i$. The event that $Y\ge c\sqrt{\log(n)}$ is the complement of the event $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \left\{X_i < c\sqrt{\log(n)} \right\}$. Since the $X_i$ are iid, it follows $$\mathbb{P}\left(Y \ge c\sqrt{\log(n)}\right) = 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(X_1 < c\sqrt{\log(n)}\right)^n$$ as noted in geetha290krm's comment. Accordingly, to obtain a lower bound on LHS, we should find an upper bound on $\mathbb{P}\left( X_1 < c\sqrt{\log(n)} \right)^n$. Now the standard Gaussian tail bound is useful: letting $p_{X}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}$ denote the density of an $N(0,1)$, we have
$$\left(\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^3} \right) p_{X}(t) \le \mathbb{P}(X > t) \le \frac{1}{t} p_{X}(t)$$ (a proof can be found in e.g the second chapter of Vershynin's text *High dimensional probability*). We have $$\mathbb{P}\left(X_1 > c\sqrt{\log(n)} \right) \ge \frac{1}{c\sqrt{\log(n)}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{c^2 \log(n)} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-c^2 \log(n)/2) $$ $$= \frac{1}{c\sqrt{\log(n)}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{c^2 \log(n)} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{n^{c^2/2}}$$ We can find $N = N(c)$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{c^2\log(n)} \right) \ge \frac{1}{2} \implies \mathbb{P}\left(X_1 > c\sqrt{\log(n)}\right) \ge \frac{C}{n^{c^2/2}\sqrt{\log(n)}}$$ for absolute constant $C = 1/(2\sqrt{2\pi})$. It follows that $$\mathbb{P}\left(X_1 < c\sqrt{\log(n)} \right)^n \le \left(1 - \frac{C}{n^{c^2/2}\sqrt{\log(n)}} \right)^{n} \le e^{-Cn^{1-c^2/2}\sqrt{\log(n)}}$$
where the last inequality follows from $1-x \le e^{-x}$ for $x > 0$. We conclude $$\mathbb{P}\left(Y \ge c\sqrt{\log(n)}\right) \ge 1 - \exp\left(-Cn^{1-c^2/2}/\sqrt{\log(n)}\right)$$ for all $n\ge N(c)$. Thus, we conclude as long as $c$ is chosen smaller than $\sqrt{2}$, the right hand side approaches $1$ as $n \to \infty$ (and, in particular, can be made larger than $1/2$ as desired).

Comment: Thank you, I owe you my life.